# Error in make make_column_transformer data transformation pipeline in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor

# Selective Attributes
actual_nan_labels = ['LotFrontage', 'MasVnrArea']
housing_cat = housing.select_dtypes(include='object').copy()
false_nan_colls = list(d.Columns)
false_nan_colls = [coll for coll in false_nan_colls if coll not in ['MasVnrType','Electrical']]
ordinal_labels = ['MSZoning', 'Street', 'Alley', 'LotShape', 'LandContour', 'Utilities', 'LotConfig', 'LandSlope', 'Condition1', 'Condition2', 'BldgType', 'HouseStyle', 'ExterQual', 'ExterCond', 'BsmtQual', 'BsmtCond', 'BsmtExposure', 'BsmtFinType1', 'BsmtFinType2', 'HeatingQC', 'KitchenQual', 'Functional', 'FireplaceQu', 'GarageType', 'GarageFinish', 'GarageQual', 'GarageCond', 'PavedDrive', 'PoolQC', 'Fence', 'SaleType', 'SaleCondition',]
onehot_labels = ['Neighborhood','Exterior1st','RoofMatl','RoofStyle','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','Foundation','Heating','CentralAir','Electrical','MiscFeature']

# Functions for custom Transformers
def replace_nan_with_no(data):
  data = data.fillna('No')
  return data

def onehotencode_func(data):
  X = pd.get_dummies(data[onehot_labels])
  data = pd.concat([data, X], axis=1)
  data.drop(onehot_labels, axis=1, inplace=True)
  return data


# Transformers
log_transformer = FunctionTransformer(np.log, inverse_func=np.exp)
replace_nan_with_no_transformer = FunctionTransformer(replace_nan_with_no)
simpleimputer_median_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='median')
most_freq_transformer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
getdummies_transformer = FunctionTransformer(onehotencode_func)


# used for transforming selective features, can take transformer or pipeline as input
preprocessing = make_column_transformer((simpleimputer_median_transformer, actual_nan_labels),
                                    (replace_nan_with_no_transformer, false_nan_colls),
                                    (most_freq_transformer, ['MasVnrType', 'Electrical']),
                                    (ordinal_encoder, ordinal_labels),
                                    (getdummies_transformer, onehot_labels),
                                    remainder='passthrough')

saleprice_preprocessing = make_column_transformer((log_transformer, ['SalePrice']), remainder='passthrough')

# PipeLines
pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessing, saleprice_preprocessing)
processed_data = pipeline.fit_transform(strat_train_set)
```

error message:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'columns'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

My guess is that make_column_transformer can't use column names after some transformation has been done by transformers by first 2 transformers, if so then how can I implement it. Do I need to break this function in small bits in a stack and convert the output of every output to data frame before passing it to next line? or is their an better or improvised way of implementing this.
this is my first time creating a data transformation pipe line so sorry due to lack of expereince with small errors

Comment: What is `d.columns` ?

Comment: Can you provide a dataset to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Corralien It is kaggle competition problem here is the [link](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

Comment: @TiredButAwake `d` is a pandas dataframe it contains all the dtype=object columns of the  original dataset which have NaN value count greater than 1 meaing those object type columns which have NaN values are stored in it for retriving them eaisyly

Comment: here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1KbOByDsjICjJF1-f_AwQbvBJ44D5BeAe?usp=sharing) of collab notebook I wrote this code on.